# Meteor - cfs-gridFS not working production server but works fine on local server

Tags: meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

I am having issues uploading images to my meteorJs app using CollectionFS/ GridFs packages. The app works fine with image upload on my localhost but when I deploy to a production server and try to upload an image, I get a broken image, and when i visit the image url, i get this error

```
Error in method "/cfs/files/:value/:value/", Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Images' of undefined
at Object.httpGetHandler (packages/cfs_access-point/packages/cfs_access-point.js:357:1)
at Object.accessPoint.get (packages/cfs_access-point/packages/cfs_access-point.js:675:1)
at packages/cfs_http-methods/http.methods.server.api.js:581:1
```

I have tried several solutions like dropping the database or even deleting and creating a new server, but the result is still the same.

I am using these packages

`cfs:standard-packages
 cfs:gridfs`

*Update*
*Code Snippet*

```
`//collection
postImages = new FS.Collection("postimages", {
stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("postimages", {})]
});
//permissions
postImages.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){return true;},
  download: function(userId){return true;}
});`
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: More information needed. Did you check in Mongo to see if  the file upload was successful?

Comment: Yes I checked and the file was uploaded into the database but when i go to  `/cfs/fils/<collection_name>/<_id>`, I get the same error

Comment: There is really no information to go on here - what does your code look like? What are the possible differences between your development machine and production? Is it a temporary directory you are using, or a file path that doesn't exist on that system?

Comment: Hello @Mikkel, sorry for the long silence. been away for a while. Here's the code update. Thanks

Comment: I would try adding `update` to your allows. Rules on production could be more strict? Or see if you get the same error, if you run `meteor --production` locally. You could also enable the global `FS.Debug = true` and see what errors that throws.